# Collinearity with a single regressor?

Tags: statistics, eviews

I'm trying to make a single regression with a set of different from each other, but Eviews keeps accusing "multicollinearity between regressors" when theres only a SINGLE regressor.

The equation specification is as follows:

liquid assets = c(1) + c(2)*rrOnTA

the data is like this:
[image]

I'm getting " near singular matrix error. Regressors may be perfectly collinear" on Eviews, which, from what I understand, makes no sense, when theres a single regressor in it.

Any help appreaciated